# Related to insertion of an element in a binary search tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

This is the method im using to insert in BST.

```
 class BinarySearchTree:Tree{
public:
void add(int data){
    if(root==nullptr){
        createRoot(data);
    }
    else{
        if(data>=root->data){
            insertRight(data);
            root=root->right;
        }
        if(data<root->data){
            insertLeft(data);
            root=root->left;
        }
    }
}
 };
```

and these are the methods of tree class

```
   public:
    Node* root;
    Tree(){
        root=nullptr;
    }
    void createRoot(int val){
        Node* root=new Node(val);
        root->left=root->right=nullptr;
    }
```

inside tree class:

```
 void insertLeft(int val){
        if(root==nullptr){
            createRoot(val);
        }else{
        
        Node* n=new Node(val);
        n->left=root->left;
        root->left=n;
       }}
       
    void insertRight(int val){
        if(root == nullptr){
            createRoot(val);
        }else{
        Node* n=new Node(val);
        n->right=root->right;
        root->right=n;
        }     
    }
};
```

can someone tell me what other methods i can implement in a Binary Tree class

i didn't create the display method in this class,how can i check my implementation

Comment: *"What other methods I can implement..."*: This is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Have a search on the internet to find the many thousands of implementations and see what others have implemented. *"How can I check my implementation"*: like with all programming, create unit tests, cover boundary cases, random input.